# Conditional sum() method in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement, sum, subtotal

I'm having some trouble calculating subtotals in a table. Basically I have 3 columns of variables; FRUIT, ORIGIN, and PRICE. FRUIT contains things like "Apple", "Banana", "Orange", etc. I want to populate a table that shows the total price of the FRUIT column clustered by the values in the ORIGIN column. I may be overlooking an easier way of doing this, but here's what I've tried.

```
  for(i=0;i<FRUIT.length;i++)
  {
  if(ORIGIN[i] == "Africa")
  {
  SUBTOTAL.push(PRICE[i])
  }
  }
```

I then use the following method to allow me place SUBTOTAL.sum() in my table to show the total price of fruit from Africa:

```
  Array.prototype.sum = function() {
  for (var j = 0, L = this.length, sum = 0; j < L; sum += this[j++]);
  return sum;
```

The sum method works properly on the full column (for example `PRICE.sum()`) but I get incorrect subtotals using my current if statement. It also throws off the figures in my table which were previously correct before I added it, such as `PRICE.sum()`.

Any recommendations would be greatly appreciated!

Many Thanks,
Karl

Comment: Why do you need to use an if there? Maybe it's easier for you to store subtotals in an object (origin -> subtotal pairs) and build your logic on top of that?

Comment: Provide a working example on jsfiddle.net or jsbin.com so someone can help.